# delete one table with join on multiple table with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to delete a row from skills_jobs table

following is my query

```
delete from skills_jobs skj inner join jobs j on skj.jobid=j.id inner join users u on u.id=j.userid where u.id=$userid
```

but it throws the following error;

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'skj inner join
>   jobs j on skj.jobid=j.id inner join users u on u.id=j.userid wher' at
>   line 1 query: delete from skills_jobs skj inner join jobs j on
>   skj.jobid=j.id inner join users u on u.id=j.userid where u.id=41

Comment: You have missed `on` for join statement.

Comment: @Shaunak Shukla I have changed my query still the same problem

Comment: Are you sure, your table name is 'skills_jobs' ?

Comment: @Shaunak Shukla yes it is skills_jobs

Comment: You must set table, from which you remove row, see my answer.

Comment: Hey!! Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set table, from which you remove row, then try:

```
DELETE skills_jobs from skills_jobs INNER JOIN jobs j ON skills_jobs.jobid=j.id INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=j.userid WHERE u.id=$userid
```

See section "Multi-Table Deletes" from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
skills_jobs skj inner join jobs j on skj.jobid=j.id
```

You forgot on in the syntax

So the correct syntax will look like this:-

```
delete from skills_jobs skj inner join jobs j on skj.jobid=j.id inner join users u on u.id=j.userid where u.id=$userid
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from skills_jobs skj 
inner join jobs j ON skj.jobid=j.id 
inner join users u ON u.id=j.userid 
where u.id=$userid
```

Try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM skills_jobs skj INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id=skj.jobid INNER JOIN 
users u ON u.id=j.userid 
WHERE u.id=$userid
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 1):

```
 DELETE FROM skj USING `skills_jobs` AS skj
 INNER JOIN `jobs` AS j ON skj.`jobid` = j.`id`
 INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id` = j.`userid` 
 WHERE u.`id` = $userid
```

If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table.

Another structured answer:

```
DELETE skj FROM `skills_jobs` AS skj
INNER JOIN `jobs` AS j ON skj.`jobid`=j.`id` 
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id`=j.`userid`
WHERE u.`id`=$userid
```